# Add zip to a http post request

Tags: http, multipart

How do you add a zip to a post request multipart/form-data?

The above uploads the zip, but when I download it it unzip to a .cpgz and if I unizp that it creates a .zip, and just cycles.

Comment: Why would you post a **zip** file with a **txt** file extension?

Comment: What language is this code written in?

Comment: This is written in Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Content-Disposition` header to specify a `filename` that matches the actual name of the file you are uploading. You should also be setting the `Content-Type` to either `application/zip` or `application/x-zip-compressed` so the server knows the uploaded data is a zip file.

```
$bytes = Get-Content "C:\Users\User\Test.zip" -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0
$parameters = "
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"Test.zip`"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

$bytes
--$boundary--"
```

Comment: I implemented the changes you described and it still happens. I can download the zip but it just unzips into the original creating an endless cycle. Would that be an error in the $bytes? So it's correct that I'm putting bytes after Content-Transfer or should it be binary? Here's an example of my binary data: 165 166 205 48 156 250 39 89

Comment: You are putting the bytes in the correct place, but the bytes you have shown are NOT the starting bytes of a valid zip file. A zip file always begins with `80 75 3 4` decimal (`50 4B 03 04` hex) - a PK signature, per the ZIP format specification that was originally written by PKWARE.

Comment: Ok so if it's a valid zip format, why would it create an unzipping cycle when I download it? I download Test.zip, it will unzip to Test.zip.cpgz, which will unzip to Test.zip and cycle over. If I open it in windows, it will say that the zip is invalid.

Comment: It is an invalid file, and your unzipping program is not coping with that. A Google search reveals many people having a similar problem when opening an invalid zip file.

Comment: I post request the correct binary, it starts with `80 75 3 4`, but the downloaded zip starts with `56 48 32 55` Does this mean the server is misinterpreting what I'm sending it? Also the zip I download is almost 4x as large as the file I upload.

Comment: Bytes `56 48 32 55` are an ascii string `"80 7"`. Look familiar? It would seem that your file bytes are being converted from their original numeric values into string representations of the numeric values. My guess would be that PowerShell is doing that conversion when formatting your request string with a byte array as input.

Comment: Your right, I opened up the files with hex viewers. That's strange because I'm posting the binary and I can see that it is posting the binary. Is the server not interpreting `Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed`?

Comment: what EXACTLY do you see?  Are you looking at the raw data being transmitted (and if so, can you please update your question to show that?), or are you looking at the data from within PowerShell?

Comment: I'm looking at what httpbin is reporting, the data from within PowerShell, and hex viewer. Here's how I see it, I'm getting the byte equivalent from the file, stored in a byte[]. I'm then writing them to the header. Which is then interpreted as ascii somehow. The first line of the hex dump are as follow: `00000000: 38 30 20 37 35 20 33 20 34 20 32 30 20 30 20 30  80 75 3 4 20 0 0`
The content-transfer-encoding should tell the server that this isn't ascii, and that is what confuses me.

Comment: This definitely feels like a PowerShell formatting issue. The hex string `"38 30 20 37 35 20 33 20 34 20 32 30 20 30 20 30"` decodes to ascii string `"80 75 3 4 20 0 0"`. So you are not sending the actual binary bytes, you are sending a string representation of the bytes. Can you please update your question to show the entire PowerShell code you are using to create and send the HTTP request?

Comment: I believe so too, but I'm not sure how. Get-Content returns a byte[] and I'm writing into the header, which the server should interpret at binary, Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary.

Comment: But that does not mean PowerShell is interpreting the data as binary, though. You are concatenating a byte array into a string, and apparently PowerShell is converting the bytes into string characters, messing up your HTTP post. I don't how to make PowerShell not do that. You might have to manually encode the bytes to base64 and then put that data in your request, setting the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to `base64` instead of `binary`. But that requires the server to support base64 encoded posts.

Comment: But when I just print the bytes by themselves they come out the same. `80 75 3 4 20 0...` Which makes me want to believe something is wrong with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` Unless of course `80 75...` is not binary encoding.

Comment: WHERE and HOW are you printing the bytes?

Comment: I'm printing in the code where I put `$bytes`. And I print it with Write-Host. I realize that powershell might be converting the byte data in the background. I"m not sure what it's suppose to look like. Is it suppose to look like `PK........6o.E.R`?

Comment: Just tried it with base64 encoding and it's the same result. The server takes it up at ascii.

Comment: Yes, the raw binary bytes should look like `PK........6o.E.R` when viewed as-is as text, such as in a hex viewer. That is what you want uploaded when you use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` - the raw bytes - but that is not what PowerShell is apparently doing. It is converting each individual byte into a hex string. I do not know why or how to disable that behavior. I am not a PowerShell user. As for base64, it is an ascii-compatible encoding of binary data, and a core MIME encoding, that is why I mentioned it as a *possible* solution, if the server supports it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I greatly appreciate it! I'll have to look into that more.